# Forbidden error while retrieving details of cluster using <publicServiceEndpointURL> with REST kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-cluster

Trying to retrieve details of the kubernetes cluster like namespaces and pod details using kubernetes API
following  [doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_api_install#kube_api)

API:

```
<publicServiceEndpointURL>/api/v1/namespaces
Headers:
Authorization: bearer <id_token>
```

`<id_token>` - An IAM token generated.

will get an certificate error on postman with SSL certificate enabled else throwing 403 Forbidden error

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Result with disabling SSL certificate verification.

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "kind": "namespaces"
    },
    "code": 403
}
```

Tried with curl and will result in same error

```
curl -k <publicServiceEndpointURL>/api/v1/namespaces -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"
```

Error on chrome with API call

```
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

How will i able to access this API?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right permissions to list namespaces in the cluster? If you log in as the same user via the CLI, for example, can you run `kubectl get namespaces`? It looks like a permissions error. The user would need IBM Cloud IAM Reader service role (which gives you RBAC `view` role) for all namespaces in the cluster.